# git auto convert file from CRLF to LF not working

Tags: git, git-config

On our system, we used to be able to convert all CRLF to LF while committing file into git. Now this feature is gone.

Here is what I've done:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

After doing the above, I use the following command to check:

```
git config --list
```

The result is:

```
... 
core.autocrlf=input
...
core.autocrlf=false
...
```

It's very puzzling. While there's two entries of `core.autocrlf`, and the first one is `core.autocrlf=input`? If I unset `core.autocrlf` using:

```
git config --global --unset core.autocrlf
```

I still get one entry when I list git config:

```
core.autocrlf=input
```

Step 2:
After I did `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, I add `* text=auto` into `.gitattributes` file.

But git still does not automatically convert line break for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since git1.8.1rc1 :

> "git config --get" used to diagnose presence of multiple definitions
>   of the same variable in the same configuration file as an error, but
>   it now applies the "last one wins" rule used by the internal
>   configuration logic

So your second setting apply.

For more explaination on option for core.autoctrlf :

> If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true – this converts LF
>   endings into CRLF when you check out code:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

> You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but not the other way
>   around by setting core.autocrlf to input:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

> If you’re a Windows programmer doing a Windows-only project, then you
>   can turn off this functionality, recording the carriage returns in the
>   repository by setting the config value to false:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

more explanation :
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: The problem was core.autocrlf=false, once I set to core.autocrlf=input, it worked. Thank you so much!!!